# Displaying Black Triangle When I Use Page Break or Horizontal Line in CKeditor5

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, ckeditor, ckeditor5, adminlte

The black triangle display when I using  Page Break or Horizontal Line. Actually my problem is same with [this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/210) and [this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/214) which is displaying an black triangle when try to display an HTML code from CKEditor5 after I save into database. The solution is change some config in angular.json but I not using Angular, I using Codeigniter, AdminLTE and CKEditor5 from builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with script:

```js
const blackTriangles = document.querySelectorAll('.ck.ck-reset_all.ck-widget__type-around');
blackTriangles.forEach(item => { item.remove() });
```